# Android - How to place an item on a layout relatively to the top?

Tags: android, android-layout

How could I proceed to place an item on a LinearLayout, with a given space from the top? For instance, I would like to place the logo on the half of the top middle of the layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add percentages.

- You can add two layouts with the same weight to split the screen in two and then add the logo with a centered gravity to the upper layout,
- Or you can measure the screen and add the right amount of margins.

Comment: I want to target as many screens as possible, so the second point is not an option. I will go with your first option, thanks :)

Comment: @Amokrane you can always measure the screen and set the margin during runtime. Anyhow, yes, I believe the first one is a simpler option.

Comment: Good point. Any idea how I could measure the screen during runtim?

Comment: You can use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();` See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [paddingTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingTop) attribute of the view class.

Comment: Sure paddingTop is relevant, but the question was more about passing ratios rather than absolute values.